# ArcPy ListLayers to use as FME parameter

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm not sure if this is more a Python, FME, or Esri question...

So here's the situation - a user has a MXD document open connected to an ArcSDE database with a version.  I created a FME workbench to write to this database but the user doesn't want to manually type in the ArcSDE version name as a user parameter (how it's currently setup).  Instead they want what ever version they are current connected to in the MXD to be used in the workbench.

I've scraped together some Python code I've found to create a text file of the current version name for an open MXD but I'd like to use this value (or maybe instead the returned value) as a new Scripted (Python) private parameter to use in the FME workbench.

Two issues right now:

1. It lists the version name for all layers (I just want one record so I can pass one value to FME)
2. It writes to a text file.  Should it just return the version name so FME can use it as a parameter?  If so, how do I do this?

Here's the code I have so far (I'm a Python novice so please bear with me!)

```
import arcpy, os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'CURRENT')
text_file = open("C:\\temp\\VersionName.txt","w")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("SERVICEPROPERTIES"):
        servProp = lyr.serviceProperties
        if lyr.serviceProperties["ServiceType"] != "SDE":
            print "Service Type: " + servProp.get('ServiceType', 'N/A')
        else:
            text_file.write (servProp.get('Version'))
text_file.close()        
del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all layers use the same version, you could do this:

```js
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'CURRENT')
layer_list = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
first_layer = layer_list[0] #The first item in layer_list
servProp = first_layer.serviceProperties #Get properties for the first layer
version = servProp.get('Version') #Get the version
```

To use the version name as a parameter in FME, you would use a PythonCaller transformer and set "version" as the attribute to expose. See https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/How_To/Python-and-FME-Basics for documentation.

Good luck!

Tom